# Android Transparent Dialog Still Shows Black Background And Doesn't Wrap Around Content Completely

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, transparent

In this code piece i've built a dialog, a textView and put the textView inside the Dialog.

```
TextView progressHolder = new TextView(activity);
progressHolder.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
progressHolder.setText("la la la3");
progressHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

mProgressDialog = new Dialog(activity);
mProgressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(R.color.transparent));
mProgressDialog.setContentView(progressHolder);
mProgressDialog.show();
```

Displaying this dialog is supposed to show the words "la la la3" on screen with the activity showing behind them.

What actually happens is that most of the activity is revealed but the words described appear in a small black box that only wraps around the words width but has a big top margin.

For question sake, i'm not trying to show a textView but the bug still happens with this exact code.

Help anyone?

Comment: try this:http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/create-a-transparent-progress-dialog-on-android/

Comment: I'm afraid i'm working in a library -> I can't define XML resources -> I can't define the style he's defining in his tutorial. I could use a java only solution :/

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
    mProgressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

Comment: This doesn't help, the problem stays the same. thx for offering.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code..

```
yourDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove black background colour use

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```